# Replace new line characters with \r

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using [hl7parser](https://github.com/artifacthealth/hl7parser) to parse ADM files.

The documentation states that to create a new Message object, a string should be passed:

```
var message = hl7parser.create("MSH|^~\&|||||20121031232617||ADT^A04|20381|P|2.3||||NE\rEVN|A04|20121031162617||01\rPID|1|16194|16194||Jones^Bob");
```

Notice that the string uses `'\r'` to separate segments (MSH, EVN, PID).

I'm fetching the data from a server, which returns for instance the following data.

```
MSH|^~\&|EPICADT|DH|LABADT|DH|201301011226||ADT^A01|HL7MSG00001|P|2.3.1|
EVN|A01|201301011223||
PID|||MRN12345^5^M11||APPLESEED^JOHN^A^III||19710101|M||C|1 CATALYZE STREET^^MADISON^WI^53005-1020|GL|(414)379-1212|(414)271-3434||S||MRN12345001^2^M10|123456789|987654^NC|
NK1|1|APPLESEED^BARBARA^J|WIFE||||||NK^NEXT OF KIN
PV1|1|I|2000^2012^01||||004777^GOOD^SIDNEY^J.|||SUR||||ADM|A0|
```

Replacing the `\n` with `\r` with `replace()` doesn't make the parsing work, neither does `split('\n')` and `join('\r')`.

I noticed that there is a difference when logging the string passed in the example and the string after replacing with `\r`

**With string in example:**

```
PID|1|16194|16194||Jones^BobADT^A04|20381|P|2.3||||NE
```

It's only printing the last segment apparently because of the `\r` characters

**With my replacement method:**

```
PID|||MRN12345^5^M11||APPLESEED^JOHN^A^III||19710101|M||C|1 CATALYZE STREET^^MADISON^WI^53005-1020|GL|(414)379-1PV1|1|I|2000^2012^01||||004777^GOOD^SIDNEY^J.|||SUR||||ADM|A0|
```

The entire string is printed, not just the last segment.

I'm not sure why there is a difference when printing them. Is there a difference between passing a literal string with `\r` character and "adding" `\r` to a string?

Comment: Whats the question?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this should work:

```js
const lines = "A\nB\nC";
const result = lines.split("\n").join("\r");
console.log(result);
```

The confusion probably comes from the fact that it looks like it didn't, since it looks like it just output `ABC`.

However, if we check out the length of the string produced:

```js
const lines = "A\nB\nC";
const result = lines.split("\n").join("\r");
console.log(result);
console.log(result.length);
```

Notice that it is 5 characters long, not 3. The `\r` is there. It's just that when it is output to most things, it basically gets hidden because an `\r` doesn't really render to anything on its own.

It is a "carriage return" and only MacOS (before X) used it as a newline character. Windows uses a combination of `\r\n` to render a newline and Linux (and MacOSX) uses `\n`.

If it wanted an explicitly shown in the string `\r`, then you'd need to use an escaped one (though this is almost certainly not what it expects):

```js
const lines = "A\nB\nC";
const result = lines.split("\n").join("\\r");
console.log(result);
console.log(result.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

function replaceLfWithCr(text) {
   return text.replace(/\n/g, '\r');
}

Comment: Please explain your answer. Especially the modifier in the regex!